# Не открываються ссылки телеграм, что делать?

Tags: telegram

Возможно мой вопрос немного не попадает в тематику форума, просто я не знаю где еще искать ответа.

Вот такая ошибка при попытке открытия ссылок Telegram, как решить данную проблему ? Может у кого была такая проблема ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы открыть ссылку нужно в меню пуск написать  "приложения по умолчанию"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее открываем пункт приложения по умолчанию или что то типо того
И там спускаемся вниз и ищем пункт веб браузер а далее выбираем что то из предложеного